# Azure Data Factory pipeline to start SSIS Integration Runtime authorization error

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I created a Web task in Azure Data Factory to start/stop SSIS Integration Runtime. However, when I try to run the pipeline, I keep getting this error - Activity Start My IR failed:

> {"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client
>   '2b36c922-34cf-43d8-be05-5d757017e2ed' with object id
>   '2b36c922-34cf-43d8-be05-5d757017e2ed' does not have authorization to
>   perform action
>   'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationruntimes/start/action'
>   over scope
>   '/subscriptions/e8e76bdc-4591-4936-9899-31bffef9c5cd/resourcegroups/XXXXXBI-RG/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/XXXXXBI-DF/integrationruntimes/XXXXXSSIS-IR'."}}

I followed this instruction - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime

For Authentication, select MSI to use the managed identity for your ADF, see Managed identity for Data Factory article for more info.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error, you may not add the service principal to the ADF as a role.

You need to assign the managed identity for your ADF a `Contributor` role to itself, so Web activities in its pipelines can call REST API to start/stop Azure-SSIS IRs provisioned in it.

Follow the `step 5` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime#create-your-pipelines):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks. I did not think that I needed to make my data factory a contributor to access my own data factory, so I skipped that step.