# Is there any situation where a data factory needs to be Owner of an Azure subscription?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I happened to notice that a data factory (ADFv2) is owner of one of our Azure subscriptions. This is a typical ADF and not doing anything out of ordinary. I am guessing this was done by mistake -- but just want to ask here in the forum if there can be a genuine scenario where data factory needs to be owner of a given subscription?

Comment: also -- the data factory exists in the same subscription.

Comment: We are not clear about your question. Can you show us some screenshots?

Comment: Do you have any other concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what @Nandan said is basically correct, more specifically, essentially the `Owner` is assigned to the MSI of your ADFv2, when you need to use the [MSI(managed identity)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity) of your ADFv2 to auth to Azure resources/call Azure REST APIs, the [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)(in your case, it is `Owner`) is needed, to do most of the things, some other roles are enough e.g. `Contributor`, to do something like [create role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/RoleAssignments/Create), you need the role has the higher privilege, e.g. `Owner`.

Three specific cases I answered to help you understand:

1. [How to call a REST API using Azure Data Factory Pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956627/how-to-call-a-rest-api-using-azure-data-factory-pipelines)
2. [How can I use this API in Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317140/how-can-i-use-this-api-in-azure-data-factory/58317404)
3. [Azure Data Factory pipeline to start SSIS Integration Runtime authorization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503245/azure-data-factory-pipeline-to-start-ssis-integration-runtime-authorization-erro)

Answer (score 1):

Is the Azure data factory used for any automation purposes using REST APIs, etc ?
Like scaling resources or pausing/resuming resources across RGs?

If that is the case, then the ADF might have been given owner access on subscription for MSI in all the objects within RGs present in the subscription.

If this ADF is specific to data ingestion use cases, then there is no need to provide the ADF owner access on the entire subscription.